# Append a new line to an existing field in MySQL database using Python

Tags: python, mysql, quote

I'm using Python to works with MySQL database. I want to append some new line to an existing field in database. How can I do that in Python :

```
cmd = 'UPDATE table SET field= CONCAT(field,'\r\nThis is new line')'
```

This command got some errors with backlash and quote characters in either Python or MySQL.
Any suggestion for me? Thanks a lot!

Answer (score 1):

String escaping can be a little confusing when you're inlining SQL strings within Python.  However, since Python supports both full quotes as well as single ticks for declaring strings, you can correctly-escape the SQL statement via using outer quotes:

```
cmd = "UPDATE table SET field= CONCAT(field,'\r\nThis is new line')"
```

Answer (score 1):

try [triple quote](https://docs.python.org/3/tutorial/introduction.html#strings):

```
cmd = """UPDATE table SET field= CONCAT(field,'\r\nThis is new line')"""
```

Answer (score 0):

Starting from pandas 0.14, you have to provide directly the sqlalchemy engine, and not the connection object:

```
from sqlalchemy import create_engine
engine = create_engine("mysql+mysqldb://<user>:<password>@<host>[:
<port>]/<dbname>")
combined.to_sql("cps_raw.cps_basic_tabulation", engine, if_exists='append')
```